# Open multiple browsers in normal + incognito mode

Tags: batch-file

I have a .cmd file that I use to enter a URL and then have multiple browsers open it:

```
@echo off
Set /p "var=enter the URL: "
Start "" chrome "%var%"
Start "" brave "%var%"
Start "" ednge "%var%"
```

Is there an option to open the incognito versions of these browsers too along with the normal ones?

The goal is to have 3 browsers open the same URL both in normal and incognito mode.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of https://superuser.com/a/1576351

Comment: All these browsers accept command line startup options. Should be real easy to find those options by going to the vendors website or Google searching. You could have searched this site for incognito and found a solution

Comment: @Squashman Not an experienced coder, so I that's why I decided to see if anyone can point me towards what I'm missing to make it work.

Comment: Has nothing to do with coding. Learn to use a piece of software has absolutely nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little example for what you want to achieve !

---

```
@echo off
Title In order to observe, you have to be incognito !
Set /p "var=Enter the URL: "
Start "Chrome Browser" /MAX "chrome.exe" --incognito "%var%"
Start "EDGE Browser"  /MAX "msedge.exe"  --inprivate "%var%"
```